# grid with dynamic content within scrollviewer does not scroll

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I have a grid within a scrollviewer.  I add RowDefinitions and content to the grid during the page's OnNavigateTo().  When the scroll is needed, the vertical rail appears but the bottom scroll arrow is missing and it doesn't scroll.  I believe it has something to do with the heights of the grid and scrollviewer, but I'm at a loss for how to fix it.

```
        <ScrollViewer x:Name="listScrollView" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" VerticalScrollMode="Enabled" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Height="733" Margin="0,0,0,0" Width="1010" Grid.RowSpan="2" ZoomMode="Disabled">
    <Grid x:Name="listPanel" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1010" Grid.RowSpan="2">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: Need more info such as entire xaml page and how many rows you are adding etc. Its usually better to use "*" notation for heights.

Comment: @Jon is correct. Also, when you use `RowDefinition Height="Auto"`, that will draw beyond the end of the space. As he mentioned, `*` will only use as much space as given.